# how to access a variable on main timeline from a class in AS3?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, variables

I have seen several posts of this same question asked and there is no clear answer.

main timeline:

```
var mynum:Number = 0;
```

How would I access/alter this variable from the code in an external class file?
Everything I try returns the "instance does not exist error"

Comment: `MovieClip(root).mynum` with the gotcha that the class has to be a `DisplayObject` and it has to be added to the stage.

Comment: it works when I add the movieclip to the stage by dragging it from the library but when I declare it with code it throws an error

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to run the code within the constructor, which would mean that it runs before you get a change to `addChild` it to the stage. You can use the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event to wait until that happens before trying.

Comment: give me a few minutes to redo the code and try that

Comment: I dont know why I am getting the error "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event." this is my class file

    `package classes
    {   import flash.display.MovieClip;
 public class myclass extends MovieClip 
    {  public function myclass() 
 
 
 
 
 {
  addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  function init(e:Event):void 
  {
      trace(MovieClip(root).mynum);
  }
 }
 
 
 
 
 }
 
}`

Comment: `import flash.events.Event`

Comment: omg right, I am an idiot

Comment: Works great, can you add it as an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Comment: Sure, 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `DisplayObject`s that are part of the display tree (either directly on the stage or as a descendant of any `DisplayObjectContainer`s on the stage) have access to `root`, which will either refer to:

1. The `MainTimeline` if there is no document class present.
2. The document class if one is present.

Casting `root` to `MovieClip` will make it be treated as `dynamic`, meaning variables and functions that you declare on the main timeline will be accessible without compile-time errors, meaning you can do this:

```
trace(MovieClip(root).mynum);
```

Because the child has to be on the stage at the time of the code being executed, this cannot be placed directly in the constructor for objects that are added dynamically with `addChild`. However, you can leverage the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event to wait for the object to be added to the stage first:

```
public class Example extends Sprite {
  public function Example() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);
  }

  protected function added(event:Event):void {
    trace(MovieClip(root).mynum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set the class to automatically look for variables in the timeline so i dont have to add `MovieClip(root).` a million times? I will not be creating any new variables in my class file